# high event processing in twisted

Tags: python, multiprocessing, twisted

I need to write an app that can receive, process, and then send events at ~15k Events Per Second (EPS).  I've been learning twisted and have been using it to benchmark some tests:

```
Twisted RX only = ~90K EPS
Twisted RX and TX = ~45K EPS (basically half of RX only)
Twisted RX, processing, and TX = ~6K EPS (close, but not 15K EPS)
```

The processing portion is mostly a [single regex matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871602/optimizing-regex-to-fine-key-value-pairs-space-delimited) - a task that is CPU-bound.  I tried using `threads.deferToThread` and callbacks but, as expected, didn't improve the CPU-bound processing.

My server has 256 cores and I'd love to be able to put them to use while using twisted.  Can I wrap multiprocessing in with twisted?  Each process needs to share a `dict`, so I'd have to use [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).

Can multiprocessing be done within twisted?  Is there a faster way run CPU-heavy tasks (regex expressions) in parallel within twisted?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715217/mix-python-twisted-with-multiprocessing. The accepted answer is from the founder of twisted, so he's a fairly the authoritative source.

Comment: related: "[Powerhose](http://powerhose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) turns your CPU-bound tasks into I/O-bound tasks so your Python applications are easier to scale." (I like the quote: it applies to twisted too)

Comment: [`regex` module (drop in `re` replacement)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) can release GIL. You could try it with `deferToThread` and see whether it improves things.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - good idea with the `regex` replacement - my results shows that it is actually slower than standard `re`.  3484 EPS using `regex` and concurrent=True, 6414 EPS using `re`.  Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll play with it a little more to see if I squeeze any more efficiency out of my regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the commenter, I would point at [Glyph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720492/3334178) for the multiprocessing question.

With that you could spawn off a fleet of blocking regex matching processes and communicate with them via the childFDs `IProcessProtocol.childDataReceived` and `IProcessTransport.writeToChild` methods.

This would let your twisted reactor continue to run at full speed and should get you a lot closer to your non-processing numbers (minus the cpu time for managing the extra file descriptors (though that should be tiny as compared letting the regex block the reactor))